# Laser for Engraving & Cutting

Tags: laser-diode

Can I use 500mw 808nm Infrared IR Laser Diode for engraving and cutting of wood, plastic and metal?ASER

https://www.banggood.com/Focusable-500mw-808nm-Infrared-IR-Laser-Diode-Dot-Module-12V-TTL-Fan-Cooling-p-1227542.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not at all about electronic design but rather a question that is entirely about physics or practical experiences of such systems.  Something very specific to *driving* the laser could be on topic; but if a given wavelength and *alleged* power output will get a given task done is not on topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  500mW at IR wavelengths cannot cut Metal. Reflection issue aside, it cannot produce the heat needed in the time needed to cut through it. The metal will absorb the heat and dissipate it away too quickly. At best, if you angle it, and paint it black or use tape, you may, may, lightly etch it.

That laser may cut balsa wood, very very not dense material, with multiple passes.

Plastic depends on the plastic type, how deep, etc.  Keep in mind that some plastic has chlorine in it, like PVC, and it will damage the lens.

**In short,  a 500 mW laser is best used to engrave, and can only really cut paper.** I struggled to cut poster board, and most cardboard, even the 1/16 inch stuff was too much to cut.  I myself own one of these lasers.

Comment: UV wavelengths lasers are better but more expensive in comparison. A 0.5 W UV will outperform a 0.5W IR laser. They work in slightly different ways too.

Comment: I understood that this laser is not suitable for cutting. Can i use this laser for engraving?

Comment: It will engrave non reflective material. How much it engraves depends on the material. I engraved fir and pine wood. Card board. White poster board depended on the speed. Darker material will engrave easier. Reflective material like metal will not.